# Pandas data conversion from Date+tz and string to Datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Fairly new to Pandas and I am loading a csv file into a Dataframe in the following way:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('Automobile.csv')
```

The file has the following columns:

- DATE with timezone (2006/02/08 05:00:00+00) , with Dtype of object
- TIME with values like 1500, 520, 2159, with a Dtype of int64.

A few lines with these values look like this in the file:
[image]

I have tried these to no avail:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('Automobile.csv',parse_dates=True)
    df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
    df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)
    df = pd.read_csv('Automobile.csv',parse_dates=True,infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],utc=False)
    df['DateTime2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']+df['TIME'].astype('str'),format = '%m-%d-%Y%H:%M:%S')
```

How would I go about creating:

- MERGEDATE column merging DATE & TIME without the timezone

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output? only `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strftime`. Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = {
    'DATE': ['2006/02/08 05:00:00+00', '2006/02/08 05:00:00+00', '2006/02/08 05:00:00+00'],
    'TIME': [1500, 520, 2159]
}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'DATE' column to datetime with timezone
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

# Convert 'TIME' column to time format ('05:00 pm')
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')

# Merge 'DATE' and 'TIME' columns into 'MERGEDATE' without timezone
df['MERGEDATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' + df['TIME']

# Display the DataFrame with the new 'MERGEDATE' column
print(df)
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

You can modify date format based on your requirement